# bufio.ScanLines with escaped new lines

Tags: go

I am trying to adapt `bufio.ScanLines` so it is aware of escaped new lines `\\n`.

Input:

```
line1 \
continues on line2
```

Expected output:

```
["line1 continues on line2"]
```

Right now the output of `bufio.ScanLines` (see example code below) is:

```
["line1 \\", "continues on line2"]
```

Example code:

```
s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
s.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

for s.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(s.Text())
}
```

What would be the best approach here? Looking for an implementation that still passes the tests in https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan_test.go.

Comment: what is `f` in your code?

Comment: Also why do you have `line1 \\` in the output if the input has only `line1 \`?

Comment: `f, err := os.Open(filename)`

Comment: \ is returned by the current bufio.ScanLines func.

Answer (score -3):

A few obvious approaches come to mind.

First, take a look at the [source for `bufio.ScanLines`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/883bc6ed0ea815293fe6309d66f967ea60630e87/src/bufio/scan.go#L276-304), it's not large and you could easily implement your own [`bufio.SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc) from scratch starting from a copy of that modified to do what you want.

Second, you could write a `bufio.SplitFunc` that called `bufio.ScanLines` in a loop, combining tokens as long as it returns ones that end in your escape character, and then returning the combined token.

Given the short size and simplicity of the first approach that's what I'd probably do. The second approach would likely end up just as long, be less efficient, and probably require state since you'd need to store the combined-token-so-far when returning `(0, nil, nil)` to ask for more input.

Another solution would be to implement a [`Transformer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/#Transformer) (from the `golang.org/x/text/transform` package) that strips relevant escaped characters from the input (e.g. removes `"\\\n"`) and use `transform.NewReader` to make a filtered reader that you'd then do use however you want (e.g. passing to a `bufio.Scanner` with the regular `ScanLines`).

In any case, you could copy the appropriate tests from `scan_test.go` as well as adding your own for the escaped newline behaviour. Beware of `bufio.MaxScanTokenSize` as well.